# creating dynamic Arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hello i want to create a array in java script withing 2 for loops

```
var i;
    var a;
    var total       = document.getElementsByName('qm[7]')   
    var creativity  = document.getElementsByName('qm[0]');
    var design      = document.getElementsByName('qm[1]');
    var text        = document.getElementsByName('qm[3]');
    var motivation  = document.getElementsByName('qm[5]');
    var depth       = document.getElementsByName('qm[6]');
    var usefulness  = document.getElementsByName('qm[8]');
    var research    = document.getElementsByName('qm[9]');

ratingArray = new Array(total,creativity,design,text,motivation,depth,usefulness,research);

for(i=0; i < ratingArray.length;i++)
{

    for(a=0; a < ratingArray[i].length;a++)
    {
        if(ratingArray[i][a].checked == true)
        {

             rateArray = new Array(ratingArray[i][a].value);
        }    
    }

}
```

and if i return rateArray it just gives the first element any idea?

Comment: The script is doing what you want it to do.  What do you want to create?  A 1D array with all the checked items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're overwriting rateArray each time you find a checked element - I suspect you meant to append it instead:

```
var ratingArray = new Array(total,creativity,design,text,motivation,depth,usefulness,research);
var rateArray = new Array();

for(i=0; i < ratingArray.length;i++)
{

        for(a=0; a < ratingArray[i].length;a++)
        {
                if(ratingArray[i][a].checked == true)
                {

                         rateArray.push(ratingArray[i][a].value);
                }        
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array and push the selected values to the new array.

A detailed description of array functions

[Manipulating JavaScript Arrays](http://www.elated.com/articles/manipulating-javascript-arrays/)

```
var ratingArray = new Array(total,creativity,design,text,motivation,depth,usefulness,research);

var selectedValArray = [];

for(i=0; i < ratingArray.length;i++)
{

        for(a=0; a < ratingArray[i].length;a++)
        {
                if(ratingArray[i][a].checked == true)
                {

                         selectedValArray.push ( ratingArray[i][a].value );
                }        
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
document.getElementsByName('qm[7]')
```

will not work. There are no elements that can have the name `qm[7]`. Did you mean this to be your array? In that case, remove the quotes, initialize the array prior to those statements and fill it with the names of the elements you want to select.

The function `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements. To use this array, you need to select the items in it. I.e.:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName("body");
var myBody = elems[0];
```

you do that correctly in your for-loops.

**Update:** expanded section and added explanation on getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

In this line you create an new Array every time:

```
rateArray = new Array(ratingArray[i][a].value);
```

So you have to push the elements in to the array instead of creating a new one every time thats also delete the last version.

```
 var rateArray =[]

for(i=0; i < ratingArray.length;i++)
{

        for(a=0; a < ratingArray[i].length;a++)
        {
                if(ratingArray[i][a].checked)
                {

                         rateArray.push(ratingArray[i][a].value);
                }        
        }

}
```